# how to disable text in textarea when prompting

Tags: javascript

I have this case in a switch which puts preprint text in a textarea when press OK on prompt.
When I press CANCEL, there appears this text in textarea:

```
<img src="null" />
```

This is the case:

```
  case 'image':
           var urlOpts = {};
           var thisOpts = $.extend(htmlOpts, {
              
              closetype: 'short'
           });
           NewURL = prompt("URL van afbeelding:",'http://');
           /urlOpts.src = NewURL;
           
           $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('img',thisOpts,urlOpts);
           break;
```

How can I disable that text when pressing CANCEL in prompt? Textarea should be left blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if statement. Because the prompt returns `null` if you press cancel, you can just check `NewURL` against `null`:

```
case 'image':
    var urlOpts = {};
    var thisOpts = $.extend(htmlOpts, {

        closetype: 'short'
    });
    NewURL = prompt("URL van afbeelding:",'http://');
    if(NewURL != null){
        urlOpts.src = NewURL;

        $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('img',thisOpts,urlOpts);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, i just saw i misread your question, i changed the answer, now the textarea won't change

Comment: Now appears:    img src="undefined"

Comment: Then you are changing the textarea somewhere else as well and we need that code as well, otherwise we can't change that

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `prompt` returns a string or null if user press cancel. So you can check if value is different from `null`:

```js
NewURL = prompt("URL van afbeelding:", 'http://');
if (NewURL != null) {
  urlOpts.src = NewURL;

  $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('img', thisOpts, urlOpts);
}
```

Comment: I can see is the same if statement as above; thanks now its working